# Automatically find tag names in RichTextField and link them to existing tags

Tags: django, python-3.x, tags, wagtail, django-taggit

I've created pages in Wagtail using 'MyPage' class and assigned Tags to them using Taggit. These tags appear ok and I can display them without issue. When clicked they load related articles on a listing page.

I'm trying to find a way to automatically convert (li) list items (with the same name as my tags) (in RichFieldText) to these tags, so I won't have to manually assign links to each list item. I'm still fairly new to Django and Wagtail and haven't found anything in the documentation so far. Would anyone have a solution?

// Where the RichFieldText is
mylist_page.html

{{ page.my_list|richtext }} // Displays my list

As this question is not getting much traction I will simplify my question. I want to convert text automatically to tags in django/wagtail. If anyone could even just tell me which direction to go in it would be much appreciated.

If you need more of my code just let me know (please be specific). Again, any help will be much appreciated.

## From models.py

```py
class MyPageTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey(
        'MyListingPage',
        related_name='tagged_items',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
class MyPage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    my_list = RichTextField(default= 'My list')
```

## From mylist_page.html

```py
            <h2 style="margin-bottom: 15px">My List</h2>
            {{ page.my_list|richtext }}
            <br/>
```

Comment: More code would definitely be helpful

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dan. What would you like to see?

Comment: I would really recommend you check out https://learnwagtail.com/course/ and do an on-page search for  'tag' and 'snippet'.  Watching the videos that you find with those searches might help.